# Backbone Relational: relation lost during saving

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational, backbone.js-collections

Today I updated backbone.js (0.9.2 => 0.9.9) and backbone-relational (0.5.0 => 0.7.0), and a piece of code stopped working and I can't figure our why. (I even tried to upgrade step by step (e.g. backbone-relational 0.5.0 => 0.6.0), but that didn't helped.)

My models (a book that contains several chapters):

```js
window.Book = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  relations:[{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key:"chapters",
    relatedModel: "Chapter",
    collectionType:"ChaptersCollection",
    reverseRelation:{
      key:"book"
    }
  }]
});

window.BookCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book,
  url: "/books"
});

window.Chapter = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend();
window.ChaptersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Chapter,
  url: "/chapters"
});
```

Now I want to add a chapter to an existing book, and do something during the "add" event. The problem is that `chapter.get("book")`is `undefined`, although the book is returned in the `success`callback. But see yourself:

```js
var book = ...;
book.get("chapters").on("add", function (chapter) {
  console.log("add");
  console.log(chapter.get("id"));
  console.log(chapter.get("book_id"));
  console.log(chapter.get("book"));
});

var chapter = book.get("chapters").create({title:"Foo"}, {
  wait: true,
  success:function () {
    console.log("success")
    console.log(chapter.get("id"));
    console.log(chapter.get("book_id"));
    console.log(chapter.get("book"));
  }
});
```

Console output:

```
> add
> 83
> 3
> null <<<<<<< Expecting a book object here, why null?
> success
> 83
> 3
> Book{...}
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could be that the relation initialization hasn't occurred yet when the add event fires. Try `_.defer(function() { console.log(chapter.get("book")); });` and see if it logs the book. If it does, that's your culprit.

Comment: Defering the call is working, but it won't help me: I am using ```Marionette.CollectionView``` (https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md) that automatically renders items on add, so I have to look for another workaround :(

Comment: It wasn't meant as a workaround, just a way to check whether that was the problem. I'll see if I have time to look at this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that when the `add` event is fired for the child collection, the reverse relation hasn't yet been updated.  I'm not sure what change in Backbone or Backbone.Relational between versions caused this change, but it's easy to fix.

Instead of listening to the `add` event on the related collection like you do here:

```
book.get("chapters").on("add", function (chapter) {
```

You should listen to the `add:<key>` event on the model itself as described in the [Backbone.Relational documentation](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational#events):

```
book.on("add:chapters", function (chapter) {
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXXaE/7/) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked great! Using the ```add:<key>```event I could hook into https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L1321 !